# WIFI URL redirection

Tags: url-routing, captive-portal

Is there some generic solution for redirecting hotspot users to some page before they get to their requested page?

No need for authorization,billing or any other captive portal capabilities.

I'm looking for the most simple solution which will not require flushing the router with DD-WRT and would work for a large portion of simple SMB businesses (e.g coffee places).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement PFSense as a routing/firewall solution, which has captive portal capability, http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Captive_Portal. I don't know if `not require flushing the router with DD-WRT` means hacking an off the shelf router or not, but PFSense can be installed on an off the shelf server or it's own appliance, no hacking necessary.